# Find pair of values for which ln series converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Define the sequence $\{u_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ as follows:

$u_n = \ln(n) + a\ln(n+2) + b\ln(n+3), n>=1$

Find the values of $(a, b)$ for which the series converges.

**My attempt:** 
I tried to generate a geometric series from it but no success.
$u_n = \ln(n) + \ln(n+2)^a + \ln(n+3)^b$ 
$= \ln[n(n+2)^a(n+3)^b]$ 
I'm stuck here.

Does finding the improper integral help in solving the problem?

Comment: Hint: $\{U_n\}$ converges if and only if $\{e^{U_n}\}$ converges to a positive number, by the continuity of $\ln x$.

Comment: @GregMartin okay. $e^{U_n}$ gives me $n(n+2)^a(n+3)^b$ . Now how do i get the limit when i don't know the values of a and b ? (a and b could be negative)

Comment: Factor out $n^{1+a+b}$ and make as many cases as you need, depending on positivity and such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\{u_n\}$ converges when $a+b = -1$.  Proof sketch:

$\{u_n\}$ converges iff $\{e^{u_n}\}$ converges to a positive number.  Therefore, we can consider the sequence
$$u'_n = n(n+2)^a(n+3)^b$$
which converges to a positive number when $a+b = -1$, because then the powers of $n$ cancel out:
$$\lim_{n->\infty} u'_n = \lim_{n->\infty} n(n+2)^a(n+3)^{-1-a} = \lim_{n->\infty} \frac {n}{n+3}\left(\frac{n+2}{n+3}\right)^a = 1$$
Additionally, note that if $a+b<-1$ then $\{u'_n\}$ converges to zero, and $\{u_n\}$ diverges to negative infinity; and if $a+b>-1$, then both $\{u'_n\}$ and $\{u_n\}$ diverge to positive infinity.

Comment: Wow okay. But how did you get to know $U_n$ converges when $a+b = -1$ ?

Comment: The intuition is that for large $n$, the $+2$ and the $+3$ are negligible, so $n(n+2)^a(n+3)^b \approx nn^an^b = n^{1+a+b}$.  Then $n^x$ converges iff $x=0$, so $1+a+b=0$.